# Checking conditional Independence of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Consider the following conditional independencies of four Random Variables A, B, C, D.

$$A \perp B \mid C, D$$
$$A \perp D \mid B, C$$

Can the following concluded from the given independencies?

$P(A, B, C, D) =P(A, C, D) P(B \mid A, D)$ and $P(B \mid A, C) = P(B \mid C, D)$

I tried to derive the conclusions, but unsuccessful. But can I gaurentee that I can never get the conclusions?

Comment: Are these events or random variables? is / the same as | ?

Comment: @Henry edited the question.

Comment: @Its_me Thanks for pointing. It's my wrong.

Comment: The first one, i.e. $P(A, B, C, D) =P(A, C, D) P(B| A, D)$ is in general only true if $P(B| A, C,D)=P(B| A,D)$, because $P(A, B, C, D) =P(A, C, D) P(B| A, C,D)$. And this is equivalent to $B \perp C|A,D$, which does not follow from your two independence statements.